# StreamWriter in server file is in use, but in local works

Tags: c#, web-services, server, streamwriter

I have a webservices's project. I'm trying to write a log per each method using StreamWriter, in my local machine everything is working fine.

Something like this:

```
static StreamWriter sw;
try{
if (File.Exists(Directorio + FILE_NAME))
   {
      sw = File.AppendText(Directorio + FILE_NAME);
   }
   else
   {
      sw = File.CreateText(Directorio + FILE_NAME);
      sw.WriteLine("---LOG ");
    }
    sw.WriteLine(Date);
    sw.WriteLine(Header);
    sw.WriteLine();
    sw.Close();//*/
}catch(Exception){}
```

But when is uploaded to the server sometimes it throws an error that can't write because the file is in use. But I close it every time and I thought that with the try catch should ignore that part and continue with the method, because I don't want to affect the process of each method.

I know that is little information, and I can't reproduce my problem here but hope that someone who had an error like this could give me a hint.

Comment: Don't bother trying to write logging that can support concurrent log writes. It's a messy business and the problem has already been solved by others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web servers typically handle multiple requests at once.  The occasional error is most likely due to one request trying to log while another request is already logging, and not yet done.

If you wish do use your own logging framework, you will need to coordinate writes to the file.

You could also use one of the exceptional, open-source logging frameworks such as [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/).

Comment: are like 4 stores writing in the file, so it's a fact that is that, right? I wasn't sure because according to my boss in another project she writes a log and this error does not happen. But thank you, I'm going to check that framework.

Comment: The difficult thing about this error is that it will almost always work in a very low volume environment (where concurrent writes to the log file are unlikely).  NLog is great.  It handles concurrency, and also gives you many options for logging.  For example, for some projects I set things up so that all issues are logged to a file, but critical issues are *also* logged to an email logging target, which is configured to send me and a few other "operations" people an email containing the log info.

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to multiple requests coming to web server and one request trying to write to this log file while other is trying to open. possible fix could be thread synchronization, which is not good as it would significantly degrade the performance of web service. **Alternatively I'd recommend using nLog (http://nlog-project.org/), used in several projects without any issues.**

Comment: Welcome to the site. While the linked resource seems a good one, it would be better to include a description of the logger in your post, as required by the [site policy](answer).